# Newby to TcpClient Server

Tags: tcpclient

I have inherited a project which involves a client connection to a server which in turn connects to another server in some instances.

The client starts a transaction which is sent to Server A which in turn sends xml to Server B. Server B returns xml to server A which returns it to client.

Each transaction requires this loop to be executed 3 or 4 times depending on client selections after the first loop has completed.

Server B requires that the connection from Server A remain open for the duration of the transaction and a sessionid is assigned as part of the return xml message after the initial connection is made.

My problem comes in when another client connects to server A and therefore a new transaction is triggered between Server A and Server B and due to my lack of experience with TcpClient programming I am unable to identify which connection is linked to each individual client. Currently there are over 200 clients and there are times when there could be upto 50 transactions at differing stages of completion.

Each client sends a unique identifier with every transaction and Server B sends a unique session id with every connection, I need to figure out a way of linking the 2 on server A.

Comment: Impossible to tell without seeing some relevant code.